# How to access Model from Controller in OpenUI5 Tutorial Step 7: JSON Model?

Tags: sapui5

In the OpenUI5 Tutorial [Step 7:JSON Model](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/70ef981d350a495b940640801701c409.html), I want to extend the tutorial. If the button is pressed, it should say Hello followed by the name entered in the text box. Could anybody help?

Comment: can you post your problematic code? without code we cannot help you

Answer (score 0):

The code in question (provided by the OpenUI5 team) is:

```js
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
   "sap/m/MessageToast",
   "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (Controller, MessageToast, JSONModel) {
   "use strict";
   return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App", {
      onInit : function () {
         // set data model on view
         var oData = {
            recipient : {
               name : "World"
            }
         };
         var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
         this.getView().setModel(oModel);
      },
      onShowHello : function () {
         MessageToast.show("Hello World");
      }
   });
});
```

In order to access the model from the controller, you would simply do:

```js
onShowHello : function () {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel(),
        sName = oModel.getProperty("/recipient/name");
    MessageToast.show("Hello, " + sName);
}
```

> @SVM, in the future, please include code in your question so that others with the same problem (or those looking to help) do not have to follow a link that may or may not exist in the future. This may explain your question downvotes.